# Load all images from database when app loads without manual action

Tags: android

My Activity Code: Note this is not my main activity, right now i am using a button to fetch images from the database but instead I need to fetch all the images when the app load.

```
public class QuotesPictures extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private String imagesJSON;

    private static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
    private static final String IMAGE_URL = "url";
    private JSONArray arrayImages = null;
    private int TRACK = 0;
    private Button buttonMoveNext;
    private Button buttonMovePrevious;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private static final String IMAGES_URL = "http://stressreliefapp.esy.es/getAllImages.php";
    private Button buttonFetchImages;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quotes_pictures);

        //Defining all the buttons
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        buttonFetchImages = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFetchImages);
        buttonMoveNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
        buttonMovePrevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPrev);
        buttonFetchImages.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonMoveNext.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonMovePrevious.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    //Using AsyncTask to load the data in the background thread and then publishing on the UI thread
    private void getImage(String urlToImage) {
        class GetImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                URL url = null;
                Bitmap image = null;

                String urlToImage = params[0];
                try {
                    url = new URL(urlToImage);
                    image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return image;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(QuotesPictures.this, "Loading Images...", "Please wait...", true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
                loading.dismiss();
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }

        GetImage gi = new GetImage();
        gi.execute(urlToImage);
    }

    // Method used to get all the images from the database using AsyncTask
    public void getAllImages() {
        class GetAllImages extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(QuotesPictures.this, "Loading Images...", "Please wait...", true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                imagesJSON = s;
                extractJSON();
                showImage();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String uri = params[0];
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(uri);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                    String json;
                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(json + "\n");
                    }

                    return sb.toString().trim();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        GetAllImages gai = new GetAllImages();
        gai.execute(IMAGES_URL);
    }

    private void extractJSON() {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(imagesJSON);
            arrayImages = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void showImage() {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = arrayImages.getJSONObject(TRACK);
            getImage(jsonObject.getString(IMAGE_URL));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void moveNext() {
        if (TRACK < arrayImages.length()) {
            TRACK++;
            showImage();
        }
    }

    private void movePrevious() {
        if (TRACK > 0) {
            TRACK--;
            showImage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonFetchImages) {
            getAllImages();
        }
        if (v == buttonMoveNext) {
            moveNext();
        }
        if (v == buttonMovePrevious) {
            movePrevious();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just execute your download method in *onCreate* method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quotes_pictures);

    //Defining all the buttons
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    buttonFetchImages = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFetchImages);
    buttonMoveNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
    buttonMovePrevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPrev);
    buttonFetchImages.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonMoveNext.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonMovePrevious.setOnClickListener(this);

    getImage("your image url");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can't believe I spend a whole day to figure it out and the solution was so simple. You are a star!!!

Answer (score 0):

Move your code at **onclicklistener** to **onResume**.

```
public void onResume()
{
   super.onResume();
   /* your code at OnClickListener */
}
```